# Average of each entry from a column values based on unique value of another column

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, pandas-groupby

I have a file which looks like:

```
E1    32    45    +   Apple
E2    54    76    +   Apple
...
...
-E2   300   400   +   Apple
-E1   540   760   +   Apple  
E1    560   600   -   Orange
E2    340   440   -   Orange
...
...
-E2   30    40    -   Orange
-E1   20    7     -   Orange
```

Here E for each unique value from last column can range from 1 to 100. And the last column can go till several thousand unique fruits. I want to estimate the average of difference in first E's (E1) from each unique value of last column.

```
E1 ((45-32)+(600-560))/2 = 26.5
E2 ((76-54)+(440-340))/2 = 61
```

I want the calculate E1, E2 and E3, and also -E3, -E2, -E1, where -E1 is last E in every unique entry from last column, similarly -E2 and -E3 are second and third last Es.

I tried groupby from pandas to approach this problem:

```
df1.groupby(str(line[4]))[line[2]-line[1]].mean()
```

I dont not know whether groupby is the right approach or not, and I am having hard time making a loop for this case. `

Comment: Do you already have this data in a dataframe i.e. `pd.DataFrame()`? With column names?

Comment: Yes I have it, lets assume the column names are A1, A2, A3, A4 and A5.